# GTK: signal 'draw' is invalid

Tags: gtk, cairo, gtk3

I'm trying to do some basic drawing and am following this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/). The code compiles fine, but I receive this error at runtime:

`GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2459: signal 'draw' is invalid for instance '0x1073ee0'`

Based off what I've read on forums, the `export-event` signal was replaced with `draw` in one of the newer versions of GTK, which confused me since GTK3 is the Ubuntu repo (running Mint).

Any ideas? Using `export-event` leads to a segfault.

Comment: Please answer your question and accept the answer, or delete the question. Leaving the question in the unanswered state detracts from questions that do need answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was missing gtk3's dev library. `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev` fixed the runtime error.

Comment: I have same problem, but `libgtk-3-dev` is installed